# Cordova v5.0 android lollipop high memory usage

Tags: android, cordova, memory-leaks, android-5.0-lollipop

since upgrading android devices to lollipop v5.0.1/v5.0.2 our Cordova apps now seem to take up loads of memory. originally seemed to max out at about 40/50 mb. Now they get to 180/200mb+.

Anybody got any idea what this could be. Have seen issues related to lollipop memory leaks. Have applied current hack/patch for memory prior to 5.1 lollipop updated but has no effect. Other native apps don't seem to be effected.

Are there any known cordova issues with lollipop or anything I may need to alter in my cordova projects?

Anybody else noticed the same issues?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This question is somewhat open ended. But, google "Android WebView Update News".  Lots of people complaining about crashing - possibly due to memory leak introduced with Google's release of updated WebView.  If this is the issue, and you uninstall the update, it might go back to it's original condition.

Comment: Thanks for this. Have updated this twice in the last few days. Maybe the WebView is now just huge (like the rest of Lollipop). Will keep and eye on these updates.

Comment: Sorry, have You more information about this? I have the same problem and I need to solve it...